# MySQL docker container HostNotFoundError with Sequelize and node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, sequelize.js

I am trying to use my MySQL docker container with node.js using Sequelize. But I keep getting HostNotFoundError. I am able to connect to the database with MySQL Workbench.
I also tried putitng "127.0.0.1 localhost" into my host file.

Error:

> C:\projects\todo-backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:96
> throw new SequelizeErrors.HostNotFoundError(err);
> ^
>
> HostNotFoundError [SequelizeHostNotFoundError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> "localhost"

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
networks:
    mysql_app:
        external: true
        
x-common-variables: &common-variables
  MYSQL_USER: todo
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: s3cret
  MYSQL_DATABASE: todos
  REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT: 8000
  
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todos
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - mysql_app
    volumes:
      - C:/projects/docker/mysql:/data/pc
```

.env:

```js
MYSQL_DB: "todos",
MYSQL_USERNAME: "todo",
MYSQL_PASSWORD: "s3cret",
MYSQL_HOST: "localhost",
MYSQL_DIALECT: "mysql"
MYSQL_PORT: 3307
```

Here I already tried "mysql", "localhost" and "127.0.0.1".

db.config.js:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.MYSQL_DB, process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME, process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    dialect: process.env.MYSQL_DIALECT,
    operatorsAliases: 0,
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,

});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.todo = require("../model/todo.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

module.exports = db;
```

When I remove the host then it tries to connect to 172.19.0.1, which is the ip-address inside the docker container.

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const db = require("./app/config/db.config.js");

db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
    console.log("Drop and Resync with { force: true }");
});


require("./app/route/todo.route.js")(app);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`)
});
```

Comment: Is the node,js service also in the same docker compose?

Comment: No, node.js doesn't run in a docker container. It's installed locally.
What I also tried now is to leave out docker and to install MySQL locally, nevertheless I am getting the same error.
What I also noticed in my host file is that there is this entry: "127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal". Could that be also conflicting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was that I was using the wrong format in the .env file. It should look like this:

```
MYSQL_DB=todos
MYSQL_USERNAME=todo
MYSQL_PASSWORD=s3cret
MYSQL_HOST=localhost
MYSQL_DIALECT=mysql
MYSQL_PORT=3307
```